# find class name using regex.match in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm devaloping a very simple Java compiler in Visual Basic. I want to parse the class name in a Java code which I paste into a textbox of my VB program. For example:

```
class MyPro {   // in this case i need to get "MyPro"
```

I used `Regex.Match` for this but I failed. Below is the code I tried:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(class)*{")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match("class mypro{")
    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine(match.ToString)
    End If
```

**Edit:**

Sometimes the source code looks like:

```
class Football extends Sports{
```

In this case I want to get `Football`.

And sometimes it is:

```
class Dog implements ISpeak{
```

In this case I want to get `Dog`.

Sometimes the classes both also *implement* and *extend*, like this:

```
class hello implements Serializable extends Object {
```

There are 4 patterns:

1. `class MyPro { //I want to get "MyPro"`
2. `class Football extends Sports{ //"Football"`
3. `class Dog implements ISpeak{ //"Dog"`
4. `class hello implements Serializable extends Object { //"hello"`

Comment: A "very simple java compiler". So far so good. In Visual Basic?! And using Regular Expressions for parsing?! Maybe give it another thought?

Comment: no compiler mean it send javac +classname.java to command prompt then java +claaname to run it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression:

```
class\s+([^\s]+)[\s\r\n{]
```

The value of the class will be captured in the group with index = 1. In C#, it would be: `match.Groups[1].Value`

Comment: a perfect answer and still there is a small problem when class has extend, implement words .i captured match.group[1] then split by space and get correct class even there is extend ,implement .but i like to know how to get class without extends,implement only using regex..